# What business identifiers are considered non-public, and should not be disclosed?

Tags: identity, business-risk

I am setting up a corporation in the US and UK and am presented with a EIN for the US, and VAT Reg. Number. for the EU.

Somewhere in the piles of documentation I have been reading, I read that the D&B (Dunn Bradstreet) number should not be disclosed, although I'm not sure why.

- Can anyone highlight the business ID numbers that are worth protecting, and the risk that it could pose if exposed?

Although I am primarily interested in corporations there may be other important data in verticals such as Construction (license #), Legal, Psychology, and government contractors that could be used to harm the disclosee in some way.

The primary concerns are "Doxxing", ID Theft, and negative reputation (e.g. credit score).

Comment: Considering that Dun & Bradstreet Numbers can be easily looked up by business address or telephone number on a D & N website I'm not sure why someone would consider them confidential either.  https://www.dandb.com/dunsnumberlookup/